# Can't properly sign out of Facebook on Android with Firebase

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I try logging into Facebook, it's working. But when I logged out, Facebook's "Sign Out" button is still showing up in my login activity and when I clicked on it, I can log out. But I don't wanna do that.

But the real question is, how do I properly sign out of Facebook? I'm using both Firebase Authentication and Facebook Authentication(with support Firebase)

**Giris.java** (Log in)

```
public class Giris extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private FancyButton buttonSignIn;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private TextView textViewSignup, textViewSifreUnuttum, girismesaji;
public boolean cancel = false;
public boolean isFirstStart;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private Dialog progressDialog;
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
private static final String TAG = "FacebookLogin";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_giris);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // Kullanıcı oturumu açtı
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                Log.d("onCreate", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // Kullanıcı oturumu kapattı.
                Log.d("onCreate", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }

        }
    };
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);

        }
    });
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
        AuthCredential credential = 
        FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        progressDialog.show();
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new 
                  OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + 
                        task.isSuccessful());

                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            finish();
                            Intent fGiris=new Intent(Giris.this, 
                            MainActivity.class);
                            fGiris.putExtra("giris","facebook");
                            startActivity(fGiris);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(Giris.this, "Facebook ile bağlantı başarız oldu.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });
    }
    else
    {
        Intent hata = new Intent(Giris.this, InternetCon.class);
        startActivity(hata);
    }
```

MainActivity.java (Log out)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private Fragment fragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
public TextView tarih;
final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
final String SHAREDPREF_DATE = "SharedPrefDate";
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser user;
private TextView textViewUserEmail;
public CircleImageView userImage;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null)
    {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Giris.class));

    }



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); //giriste gelen maili Navigation header'a at
    textViewUserEmail= (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textKullaniciBilgisi);
    textViewUserEmail.setText(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
    userImage= (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.kullaniciNavHesapResmi);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = new AraclarimFragment();
    final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Navigation itemlerinin click olaylarını burada yapıyoruz.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_cikis)
    {

        Intent gelen=getIntent();
        String loginType=gelen.getStringExtra("giris");
        if(loginType=="facebook")
        {
            finish();
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Giris.class));
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Giris.class));
        }
    }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

}
```

Comment: you are calling finish()  first.. so your logout line will not execute. put finish() at the end.

Comment: I've tried. But still the facebook sign out button is showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (id == R.id.nav_cikis)
    {

        Intent gelen=getIntent();
        String loginType=gelen.getStringExtra("giris");
        if(loginType=="facebook")
        {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Giris.class));
            finish();
        }
        else{
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Giris.class));
            finish();// must be the last line
        }
```

Comment: I think, you get me wrong. The Facebook Sign Out button is showing up, when I logged out.

Comment: Using those two logout everything 

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();`

Comment: I'm using tho. In my MainActivity.

Comment: add it at the two conditions

Comment: It worked out sir. This is so rubbish tho. Why do I have to call LoginManager in my normal Firebase Authentication? That's not make any sense.

Comment: LoginManager save all the informations about the logged session no matter what type it is, so you need to signout so clear the old session data

Answer (score 1):

when you are logout with firbase you should call facebook Loginmanager with it. bcz firebase will not logout your facebook. its just only signout your auth from firebase.

```
public void logout() {
        try {
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

you should use both logout together. otherwise it will not signout from facebook.

Comment: what is session?

Comment: its nothing just remove those condition

Comment: Sir, I'm using the  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(); and LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(); both in my MainActivity. What is difference in your code?

Comment: i m telling to use both together when you logout with firebase..  bcz firebase will not logout your facebook.. its only signout your auth.

Comment: I'm using both together tho. Check out the code in MainActivity

Comment: Oh okay, I should use them both situation. I'll try now.

Comment: in short write this both line together in else part

Comment: not in both situation. write only when you signout from firebase bcz if its from facebook only your firebase return null pointer exception

Comment: It's working on both situation. I have wrote them both situation. Should I keep the code on Firebase one?

Comment: I'm gonna ask you one question,good sir. Is it true or unnecessary process to send login type to MainActivity and log out on their situations? I think Firebase Auth and Facebook Auth(with support Firebase) is different.

Comment: i m wrong.. its not different.  you should remove those condition and write both together.. no need to pass login type to MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

```
finish();
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Giris.class));
```

you must call finish() afterwards, as the code aftr that is never reached.

Comment: You can call logout() in your first activity only i.e. Giris.class you can make a method over there and place the logout code in it and call that method from your MainActivity.

Comment: Do you mean, write the log out function in Giris, and call MainActivity?

Comment: yes, and call it from MainActivity through Giris instance.

Comment: It did not work out, sorry. But problem has been solved. Thanks for your guiding comments, mate.